# how to do streaming in nodejs using axios? with together rest api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

how to do streaming in nodejs using axios? with together rest API? i found a python example on their docs but when i try to do myself its not working, nothing is logging how do i get expected output like texts like chatgpt?

docs link: [https://docs.together.ai/docs/inference-streaming-tokens#sample-code:~:text=server%2Dsent%20event.-,Sample%20code,-Putting%20it%20all](https://docs.together.ai/docs/inference-streaming-tokens#sample-code:%7E:text=server%2Dsent%20event.-,Sample%20code,-Putting%20it%20all)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import EventSource from 'eventsource';

const url = "https://api.together.xyz/inference";
const model = "togethercomputer/RedPajama-INCITE-7B-Chat";
const prompt = "Tell me a story\n\n";

const payload = {
    model: model,
    prompt: prompt,
    max_tokens: 512,
    temperature: 0.7,
    top_p: 0.7,
    top_k: 50,
    repetition_penalty: 1,
    stream_tokens: true,
};

const headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": `Bearer xxxxxxx`,
};

axios.post(url, payload, { headers: headers, responseType: 'stream' })
    .then(response => {
      // console.log(response.data)
        const eventSource = new EventSource(url);
        eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
            if (event.data === "[DONE]") {
                eventSource.close();
            } else {
                const partialResult = JSON.parse(event.data);
                const token = partialResult["choices"][0]["text"];
                console.log(token)
                process.stdout.write(token);
            }
        };
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: You have commented out this line. what do you get with console.log(response.data) ?